# ExpressJS - Won't post new user to MongoDB (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a MEAN Stack application and trying to create a new user to add to my MongoDB. Testing this function on Postman, I keep receiving a 500 Internal Server Error. I console.log after creating a newUser in user-contoller.js but all that displays is a {_id: 5c700e93cb5c320d18bc285}.

**app.js**

```js
//

Dependency or module imports
    const path = require('path');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const helmet = require('helmet');
    const passport = require('passport');

    //Used to use enviroment variables to connect to DB
    require('dotenv').config();
    const dbconfig = require('./config/database');

    //Use this for now - have to change for development and production testing
    var url ="mongodb://localhost:27017/DB-Dev" || 3000;

    //Connecting to MongoDB - locally, development, testing, and production -- Changing dbconfig files
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(url, { 
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true 
    });

    // On database connection
    mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
      
      console.log('Connected to database');
      
    });

    // If database connection errors
    mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('Database error: ' + err);
      //winston.error('Failed to connect to database)
    })

    //Create express application
    const app = express();


    //Use helmet to set some http security headers
    app.use(helmet());

    // Imports for routing classes
    const userRoutes = require('./routes/user-routes');

    //Port for server to listen on - may change in the future
    const port = 3000;

    //CORS default allows request from anywhere - set origins or routes
    app.use(cors());

    //set static folder for client side files
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

    //Body parser middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());


     app.use((req, res, next) => {
       res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       res.setHeader(
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
         "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
       );
       res.setHeader(
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
         "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
       );
       next();
    });

    //Passport middleware
    // app.use(passport.initialize());
    // app.use(passport.session());
    // //Import passport config file
    // require('./config/passport')(passport);

    //Default all routes to the homepage
     app.get('*',(req,res) => {
       res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../angular-src/src/index.html'));
    });

    //Route handling done here
    app.use('/users',helmet.noCache(), userRoutes);


    //If there is an error, returns a 500 error
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      next();
    });



    //Start Server
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("Server started on: " + port);
    }).setTimeout = 300000; //Timeout after 5 minutes
```

**user-model.js**

```js
// Import modules and configuration files
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');


// User schema
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
});

//Using this will check for duplicate database entries 
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**user-controller.js**

```js
//Import dependencies here needed to complete middleware implementation
const crypto = require('crypto');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const validationResult = require("express-validator");

const User = require('../models/user-model');


exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then(hash => {
      const newUser = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash
      });

      newUser.save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "User has been created",
          result: result
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Invalid authentication credentials"
        });
      });
    });
} // End of createUser middleware
```

**user-routes.js**

```js
// Import dependencies 
const express = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');


// Imported controller files
const UserController = require('../controller/user-controller');

// Create a new instance of Router
const router = express.Router();

// TO - DO 
//register route follows /users/register
//middle checks array is from express-validator library. checks strings to see if they meet requirements also sanitizes html with the .escape()
router.post("/register", 
   UserController.createUser
);

//TO-DO: Authenticate 

//TO-DO: Resend Verification Email

//TO-DO: Verify Account

//TO-Do: Get User Profile

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you include the output of your Express server logs when you make a request with Postman?

Comment: All it displays is {"message" Invalid authentication credentials}

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I would put a few `console.log` statements within the `user-controller.js`.

Since firstName, lastName, email, and password are required attributes of the User model, I'd `console.log` them before attempting to create and save a new user record.

```
console.log(`***firstName: ${req.body.firstName}`)
console.log(`***lastName: ${req.body.lastName}`)
// ...
```

Trigger a HTTP request with Postman to hit the appropriate route, and then look the Express server logs to see if the data is getting from the client (Postman) into those variables on the server.

If not, set them in the request.

[Postman: Requests - Form Data](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#form-data)

Comment: When adding console.log before saving the new user record, the console outputs { _id: 5c701eee5188b21f6c3bea68 } then throws the ValidationError.

Comment: Yes, because the user isn't saving. Likely because one or more of the required user attributes are missing. `console.log(firstName)`, `console.log(lastName)`, etc, to verify these values are present.

Comment: When I `console.log(firstName)` and `console.log(lastName)`, I just receive a Internal Server Error on Postman. So these values aren't saving

Comment: Ah, so the output Postman gives you shouldn't change when adding a `console.log`. You will need to look at the output from your server (express), which is running in a terminal window. Look there for the data. To make it more visible, try this: `console.log(\`***firstName: ${firstName}\`)`

Comment: Using ``console.log(`***firstName: ${req.body.firstName}`)`` returns `***firstName: undefined` in the Express server logs then it reaches the catch block

Comment: That's good information. That means we aren't setting the firstName in the request made by Postman. Check out this page on how to add form data to the Postman request: [Postman: Requests - Form Data](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#form-data)

Comment: I changed the Form Data to x-www-form-urlencoded and although I still receive that the same error, my `console.log` statements are showing the inputted values instead of undefined

Comment: First, verify all fields are present (first, last name, email, and password). One of the other constraints is that the email is unique from all others. This could trip you up. On the first successful try, it will work, then it won't.

Comment: It did exactly that. Worked, than stopped. I even added a ``console.log(`***newUser: ${newUser}`)`` and it actually shows the object with the `_id` as well

Comment: Thank you so much!